# add data method to jquery datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have dynamically added table row to jquery datatable as follows

```
var addId = $('#data-table').dataTable().fnAddData([
                        this.AreaName,
                        this.RSPName,
                        this.DsrName,
                        this.DSRMSISDN,
                        this.Name,
                        status
                        ]);
```

Now i would like to store some info(here this variable) to tr node like $('tr').data('trdata',this).How to do this?

Comment: are you using dataTables 1.10.x or 1.9.x? (eg can the new API be used or not)

Comment: datatable Version:     1.9.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following example works on both dataTables **1.9.x** and **1.10.x** (old API).

As you have figured out, `fnAddData` returns the id of the newly inserted row. This id cannot be used along with jQuery, since jQuery results is based on how the table is presented in DOM (with pagination and sorting row `#id` wil most likely not be at position `#id`). You can get the `<tr>` associated with `#id` through the API method `fnSettings().aoData[..].nTr`, and by that add data to the `<tr>` correct. An addRow function could look like this :

```js
function addRow(this_) {
  //add the row  
  var addId = table.fnAddData([
     this_.AreaName,
     this_.RSPName,
     this_.DsrName,
     this_.DSRMISSION,
     this_.Name  
  ]);    
  //get the newly inserted TR and add this_ as trdata
  var tr = table.fnSettings().aoData[addId].nTr;
  $(tr).data('trdata', this_);  
}
```

you can test if the `trdata`-object is added correct this way :

```
$('#example tbody tr').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).data('trdata')) alert('has trdata');
});
```

see demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/6mtdj3xL/**